# How do we connect to Sybase DB using pyodbc, FreeTDS driver and an SSL port?

Tags: ssl, pyodbc, sybase, freetds

I am writing a python app that uses `pyodbc` and `FreeTDS` to connect to a Sybase DB. Here's the config -

```
pyodbc.connect('driver=FreeTDS',
  host=host, 
  database=database, 
  user=user, 
  password=password, 
  port=port)
```

This works just fine if I am connecting to a non-SSL port. I am however unable to figure out a way to connect to an SSL port, how do I provide the certificate details in the connecting parameters?

I have tried to tweak in the `freetds.conf` file, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Try UseSSL=true in conn string